# A good solution for a VR HUD?

Tags: three.js, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, webvr

I'm developing a game with THREEjs and webvr-boilerplate. I'm struggling a bit with how to properly render a HUD (score, distance, powerups etc) that always stays at the top of the scene. I've tried to have a plane (with a texture that's brought in from a hidden canvas element) but positioning it in space proves difficult since I can't match the right depth.

Any clues please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you shouldn't have a classic HUD, VR doesn't work like that.

You're searching for something called diegetic or spatial UI - that is the scores and other icons are rendered as geometry in scene space in a fixed position or distance (this one is called **spatial UI**). For best results, draw the information on some game object mimicking real displays, for example a fuel gauge on the dashboard of a car or visible remaining bullets on a gun (this one is called **diegetic UI**).

Unity has made [a nice page describing these concepts](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/user-interfaces-vr).

Answer (score 0):

I created a performance statistics HUD specifically for WebVR & THREE.js Projects.
https://github.com/Sean-Bradley/StatsVR

While the default setup shows specific information, you can modify it to show custom graphics and other data.

And if you don't believe me, just check out the
[StatVR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZNZoaiTUwg) video tutorial.
[image: StatsVR Tutorial for WebVR and ThreeJS projects]